# performseguewithidentifier with iBeacons

Tags: ios, xcode, ibeacon

im trying to build a demo app using Estimote Beacons. i want the app to open e specific viewcontroller when the user is near a beacon. im using performseguewithidentifier but when the app starts is opens only the first viewcontroller representing the first beacon which is in the range and it doesnt open the other ones when i go near the other beacons. it somehow just stops ranging for other beacons. 
below is the code im using to range for beacons:

```
func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon],
                       inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {



        let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown}

        if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {

            let closestBeacon = knownBeacons [0] as CLBeacon







            if(closestBeacon.minor.integerValue==50557){
                performSegueWithIdentifier("VC1", sender: nil)
            }

            else if(closestBeacon.minor.integerValue==37890){
                performSegueWithIdentifier("VC2", sender: nil)

            }

            else if(closestBeacon.minor.integerValue==18976){
                performSegueWithIdentifier("VC3", sender: nil)
            }





            else {


                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
            }
```

Comment: Is the code shown in the appDelegate?  Are the named segues associated with only a single viewController?  Are you sure they are being found?  If would set breakpoints or add NSLog statements to see which branch of the if statement is executing.

Comment: @davidgyoung no, the code is in the main viewcontroller and each segue is associated with a particular viewcontroller (not a single one) and yes they are being found. depends near which beacon i start the app, it shows only that one and it doesnt "fire" the other segue when i go near the other beacon. however, when i close the app and i go near the other beacon, it opens it. but i want the segues to present the associated viewcontrollers automatically when i go near that beacon (with the given minor value)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Estimote's custom library, but I assume it's similar to the location manager's.

In the Core Location Manager, if your app is in the background you get an entered region notification when you first enter a new beacon region, and then you only get ranging information for a few seconds.

If you've set up your region with a unique UUID and Major ID but no minor ID, then all beacons with that UUID and Major ID are considered part of the same region and you won't reliably get ranging notifications as the beacons with different minor IDs become the closest beacon.

If you want to handle multiple beacons in range at the same time and distinguish between them you'll need to create separate beacon regions for each beacon's UUID, Major ID **and** minor ID.

I don't know if that's the issue you're facing, but it could be.

Comment: no, thats not the issue. i just want the segues to show the associated viewcontrollers when i go near the beacon with the associated minor value. but, it shows only the first one in the range and it doesnt change to the other one when i go near the other beacon. it somehow stops ranging for other beacons. maybe there is another way of writing the code above. maybe im missing smthng...?